Different Kahler structure with different sign of the first Chern class
Is there a $2n$ dimensional manifold $M$ and Kahler structures $(J_{1},g_{1}), (J_{2},g_{2})$ on $M$, such that $c_{1}(M,J_{1})$ is positive with respect to $g_{1}$, but $c_{1}(M,J_{2})$ is negative with respect to $g_{2}$?
When $n=1$, this is impossible due to Gauss-Bonnet formula. But I don't know if it is false when $n\ge 2$.

Chern classes are topological; i.e., the cohomology class does not change when you change, say, the metric or the connection on the vector bundle.

But Chern classes depends on the almost complex structure, aren't they?

The way you stated your question focused on the metrics. See the discussion here and here. I guess if you take the conjugate complex structure, then the sign of the Kähler form does obviously change.

If I take the conjugate complex structure but fix the metric, then the sign of the Kahler form and the first Chern class change at the same time, so I think it does not change the (non-)positivity of the first Chern class.

What precisely do you mean by positivity of a form/class with respect to a metric?

Quick idea: the first Chern class is an element of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, and this is a discrete set. If there is a "path" that connects $(g_1,J_1)$ and $(g_2,J_2)$, the function $(g_t,J_t)\mapsto c_1(X,J_t)$ will be constant.

I don't know the answer, but for posterity: The Cartesian product of two $2$-spheres admits a Fano holomorphic structure ($\mathbf{P}^{1} \times \mathbf{P}^{1}$) and non-Fano structures (Hirzebruch surfaces of arbitrary even degree) containing smooth curves of arbitrarily large negative self-intersection. A comparable remark holds for Hirzebruch surfaces of odd degree.
